# Where do the historical accuracies end and fiction begin in Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter?

Tags: analysis, historical-accuracy, abraham-lincoln-vampire-hunter

There are innumerable fictions in Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter (based on Seth Graeme Smith's 2010 novel). From the existence of vampires, to the mass collection of silver to combat the Confederacy's employment of vampires in their army, most of the film deviates from real life.

**But where do the historical accuracies end and the fiction begin?**

For instance:

- Did Lincoln's mother die when he was young?
- Was his former employer a trusted aide along his side all the way to the White House?
- Was Lincoln life-long friends with an African-American who also remained at his side throughout his life?
- Did Lincoln steal Mary Todd away from Stephen Douglas?

Comment: From the look of the trailer I am guessing the answer is "at the cinema door".

Comment: From point when you hear the tittle of movie Vampire hunter

Answer (score 7):

You've got good questions, but the answers are easily found with a little research. One mustn't go farther than Wikepedia.org to find answers.

[In Indiana, when Lincoln was nine, his mother Nancy died of milk sickness in 1818](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln).

[Frederick Douglass was Lincoln's "black friend"](http://www.rense.com/general63/friend.htm). [See also the Wikipedia article for Frederick Douglass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Douglass).

[Mary was courted by Stephen Douglas, against whom her later husband notably debated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Todd_Lincoln).

[Joshua Fry Speed was Lincoln's business partner and friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Speed).

I have seen this movie, it was enjoyable, I had a good time - but I can't see that it will win an Oscar or be nominated for one.

Comment: To be fair, Evik, I am asking about the movie as a whole. The questions I asked were included *because* they are easier to find.

Comment: I think maybe your question is a little to vague to be a single question. Obviously, there is much truth and much fiction in the plot, characters, and motivations. Asking a more specific question might render more specific answers.