# Why was Abraham Lincoln chosen to be a vampire hunter?

Tags: book-adaptation, abraham-lincoln-vampire-hunter

In the movie [Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1611224/), Abraham Lincoln is portrayed as a vampire hunter. I do not understand why the producers chose him to be a vampire hunter.

Historically he is of great importance in not only American history, but also in global history. So, is it not a bad idea to choose this famous character to be portrayed as vampire hunter?

What is the reason behind choosing Abraham Lincoln? I searched Google and found a novel of the same [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln,_Vampire_Hunter_%28novel%29). So, is the movie based on the novel and that is why the character is Lincoln? Also I do not think showing him as vampire hunter is such a great idea, because it can create misconceptions with the public, which we have already seen in [this site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/where-do-the-historical-accuracies-end-and-fiction-begin-in-abraham-lincoln-vam)!

Comment: The movie is based off the novel

Comment: Why is the down-vote? Anybody care to explain?

Comment: *"So, is it not a bad idea to choose this famous character to be portrayed as vampire hunter?...Also I do not think showing him as vampire hunter is such a great idea, because it can create misconceptions with the public"* - As the author himself said in the making of, *"He's so iconic, his legacy is so strong that it can support an absurd fun treatment like this"*.

Comment: *"because it can create misconceptions with the public, which we have already seen in this site!"* - Though the asker of your linked question is fully aware that *Abraham Lincoln* most probably was *not* a vampire hunter, so I'm not sure that counts as misconception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The movie is **based on the** [**novel**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln,_Vampire_Hunter_(novel)) of the same name.

[image]

From an [**interview with the author**](http://www.vanityfair.com/online/oscars/2010/02/qa-abraham-lincoln-vamire-hunter-author-seth-grahame-smith) ***Seth Grahame-Smith*** (2010):

> ***When you got the idea for this book, were you thinking, “I sure do love Abe Lincoln, but I wish his story had more vampires?” Or was it, “I’m sick and tired of all these vampire novels without any historical context?”***
>
> - *To be honest, I don’t know which came first in that chicken or the egg scenario. I’ve been a lifelong horror fan, but at the same time, I would say 90 percent of my reading is biographies and nonfiction history. I read a lot by Doris Kearns Goodwin and David McCullough and Walter Isaacson. I’ve always enjoyed reading history, particularly presidential biographies. 
>
>   I guess where it really came from was, I like to wander around bookstores and see what people are reading. Last year, during the Lincoln bicentennial—and this was when 'Twilight' was really blowing up—it seemed to me like every book on the front shelves was either a Lincoln biography or a vampire novel. So it was like an instantaneous click in my brain.*
>
> ***You thought, “If I can find a way to combine these two genres, I will rule the world?!”***
>
> - *(Laughs.) Something like that. It was a weird chocolate-meets-peanut-butter moment for me. It was a chance to take my two favorite tastes and put them together.*

Comment: Btw, the author of the novel also wrote the screenplay for the movie.